# Compute the following finite sum: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^22^i$

Tags: summation

Compute the following sum or give me a guidance (I try to solve it by use of logarithm but I could not )
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^22^i=?$$

Comment: Some related older posts:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338852/find-a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36008/summation-by-parts-of-sum-k-0nk22k
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460470/calculate-sum-limits-i-0n-i2-cdot-2i
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912801/induction-proof-for-sum-limits-i-1n-i22i-n22n1-n2n23-cdot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try differentiation under summation,

$$
  \sum_i i^2 2^i = \sum_i i^2 2^{i x} |_{x=1},
$$

with

$$
  i^2 2^{i x} = \frac{1}{(\log 2)^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} 2^{i x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2x^i$$ Rewrite it as $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i(i-1)+i)x^i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i-1)x^i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix^i$$ $$S_n=x^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i-1)x^{i-2}+x\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix^{i-1}$$ $$S_n=x^2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{i}\right)''+x\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x^{i}\right)'$$ I am sure that you can take it from here. When finished, set $x=2$.

Comment: thank you dear Claude Leibovici.